# Ngx-bootstrap timepicker [(ngModel)] (ngModelChange) results in infinite loop

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I am using ngx-bootstrap datepicker and timepicker. I have the use case where if date selected is current date, the time in timepicker needs to be reset to current time. I set the time to current time in NgOnModelChange - timeModel= new Date().
As soon as this happens, it gets stuck in infinite loop. Model changes, NgOnModelChange keeps getting fired and browser freezes.
How do I fix this?

Comment: welcome to so. I think ngModelChange is triggered again and again due to your date input change

Comment: trying to understand use of [(ngModel)] and (ngModelChange) in your code. Do you really need both? if yes, please provide more details.

Comment: Add your code to track the issue better.

Comment: My timepicker is like this:                                                  <timepicker [(ngModel)]="mytime" (ngModelChange)="changed()" [hourStep]="hourStep" [minuteStep]="minuteStep"></timepicker>
And in the component.ts : public changed(): void { this.timeModel = new Date(); this.timeModelChange. emit(this.timeModel) ;}

Comment: I need ngModelChange to check if date selected in datepicker is today's date, if so I have to set the timeModel to current time. Basically the idea is to prevent user from selecting a past date and time to schedule a job. How else can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by replacing (ngModelChange) with (click) to track the changes.

Comment: I have same problem as well.